# update Realm table only if Record is new (Java)

Tags: java, android, realm

I am trying to update my table only if a record is new (doesn't exists yet on my stored table by checking record's objectId ) my objectId is primary key. I tried to add condition  `realm.where(NotesRealmClass.class).notEqualTo("objectId", Id);`
but it didn't seems to work how can i add a record only if record is new or we can say - stop updating the previously stored records

```
public void storeNotes( String Id, String Title ,String Location) {

    realm.beginTransaction();
    NotesRealmClass Notes = new NotesRealmClass();
    Notes.setobjectId(Id);
    Notes.setLocation(Location);
    Notes.setTitle(Title);
    realm.where(NotesRealmClass.class).notEqualTo("objectId", Id); // i tired to check if we already have the object with object Id 
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(Notes);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Notes Stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    realm.commitTransaction();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 options.

You can use method `copyToRealm()` with `try...catch`. Realm doesn't allow to create object with the same primary key and throw the exception.

```
public void storeNotes( String Id, String Title ,String Location) {
    try {
        realm.beginTransaction();
        NotesRealmClass Notes = new NotesRealmClass();
        Notes.setobjectId(Id);
        Notes.setLocation(Location);
        Notes.setTitle(Title);
        realm.copyToRealm(Notes); // <======
        Toast.makeText(context, "Notes Stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        realm.commitTransaction();
    } catch (Exception error) {
        realm.cancelTransaction();
    }
}
```

For doing the same without `try...catch` and more close to your approach you should make a fix in your code

```
public void storeNotes( String Id, String Title ,String Location) {

    realm.beginTransaction();
    NotesRealmClass Notes = new NotesRealmClass();
    Notes.setobjectId(Id);
    Notes.setLocation(Location);
    Notes.setTitle(Title);
    if (realm.where(NotesRealmClass.class).equalTo("objectId", Id).count() == 0) {
        // there are no object with this `Id`
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(Notes);
    } 
    Toast.makeText(context, "Notes Stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    realm.commitTransaction();

}
```

Comment: Well this is a more complete answer! Definitely would _not_ recommend the `try...catch` approach; exceptions are slow, and if you're attempting to insert thousands of objects that can end up being pretty expensive. The second approach is the way to go - we don't have an [`objectForPrimaryKey`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm19objectForPrimaryKeyuRdq_CS_6Object_FS0_FTMq_3keyPSs9AnyObject__GSqq__) method like they get in Swift.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if the number of objects with that id is equal to 0 - if that's true, then insert your new object:

```
if (realm.where(NotesRealmClass.class).equalTo("objectId", Id).count() == 0) {
    realm.copyToRealm(Notes);
}
```

Comment: Insert is faster than copyToRealm. So please use insert instead of using copyToRealm